# React native not able to access apis

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs, react-native

I am calling api through `fetch` in react native but its throwing following error:

> network request failed
>   - node_modules\whatwg-fetch\fetch.js:439:29 in onerror
>   - node_modules\event-target-shim\lib\event-target.js:172:43 in dispatchEvent
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:567:29 in setReadyState
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:397:25 in __didCompleteResponse
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:503:16 in 
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\vendor\emitter\EventEmitter.js:180:12
>   in emit
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:351:47
>   in __callFunction
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:116:26
>   in 
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:314:6
>   in __guardSafe
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:115:17
>   in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue

Our front end code is on localhost while the APIs are on server. I am using react native at front end and Django at back end.

Comment: Do you have CORS set up to allow "localhost" as a domain on your API which is on the server?

Comment: Hi, did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @sanders Yes, allowed CORS on back end.

Comment: @GhostCat Thanks again. It make sense :)